# How to Convert Sql to Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

My Code Sql :

```
declare @pFPId int ,@pDate datetime
select @pFPId =max(id) from __FiscalPeriod__
select @pDate =max(enddate) from __FiscalPeriod__

SELECT (select name from __StockRoom__ where FPId=@pFPId and id=1) as [نام انبار],[کد کالا], [نام کالا], [مقدار] ,
(SELECT Name FROM __Unit__ u WHERE u.Id = [واحد اصلي]  AND u.FPId = @pFPId ) AS [نام واحد اصلي] FROM __InventoryQ__(@pFPId, 1, @pDate, -1) WHERE [مقدار] > 0 
union all
SELECT (select name from __StockRoom__ where FPId=@pFPId and id=7) as [نام انبار],[کد کالا], [نام کالا], [مقدار] ,(SELECT Name FROM __Unit__ u WHERE u.Id = [واحد اصلي]  AND u.FPId = @pFPId ) AS [نام واحد اصلي] 
                   FROM __InventoryQ__(@pFPId, 7,@pDate, -1) WHERE [مقدار] > 0
```

What is your suggestion?

Comment: This tool might help you: https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: A good start would be to find an OR mapper that supports LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using Linqer: http://www.sqltolinq.com/home

It converts SQL queries to linq and helps you to learn linq.  It requires a connection string for your database so i am unable to show you the output for your above code.

There is also a great devblogs post going over conversions:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/converting-sql-to-linq-part-1-the-basics-bill-horst/